# Get the host IP address in SFML

Tags: c++, network-programming, sfml

I'm making a game where a player can host an online session. I'm using SFML network library. But I want to display the IP address of the server host when it is waiting for incoming connections. How can I get this IP address? I'm looking for the internal IP address, but if it's possible to get the external IP address, that would be a bonus.

```
sf::TcpListener listener;

// bind the listener to a port
if (listener.listen(53000) != sf::Socket::Done)
{
    // error...
}

// accept a new connection
sf::TcpSocket client;
if (listener.accept(client) != sf::Socket::Done)
{
    // error...
}
```

Comment: As I understand it, if you don't specify an interface to the [`listen`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1TcpListener.php#a9504758ea3570e62cb20b209c11776a1) function, then it will listen for incoming connections on *all* interfaces (i.e. it binds to `INADDR_ANY`). Therefore you can't get the address of any specific interface from the `TcpListener` class. Instead you have to use your platforms network functions to get a list of interfaces, and either guess which one is the correct, or just list them all.

Comment: with the stl approach, the ip adress would be right there in the recvfrom() function ;)

Comment: @Charlie One seldom use `recvfrom` on a TCP socket. Seldom one uses plain C functions too, when the `TcpSocket` class have a member function to receive data. Lastly, it's not the remove connections address the OP want, but that of the local server.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg dont get me wrong, I use SFML myself, I'm just saying that the stl approach can be more transparent sometimes

Answer (score 3):

Unless I've misunderstood your problem, you're looking for those static functions:

```
sf::IpAddress sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
sf::IpAddress sf::IpAddress::getPublicAddress(Time timeout);
```

Documentation is [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.0/classsf_1_1IpAddress.php).